# How do I unselect and select another in one gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In SwiftUI I have a bar graph, the bars are blue and when one is tapped, the opacity of all the others gets lower, to show it is selected. I also have it working with DragGesture.

When a bar is tapped, it is selected. If you tap on it again, or any other bar, it becomes unselected. I want to make it so that when I have a bar selected and then a separate bar is tapped, the second bar becomes selected. At the moment I have to tap twice. Once to unselect and second to select the second bar.

How can I modify the code to make sure that happens?

```
struct BarGraph: View {
    var exampleData: [ExampleData]

    // Gesture Properties...
    @GestureState var isDragging: Bool = false
    @State var offset: CGFloat = 0

    // Current download to highlight while dragging or tapping...
    @State var currentDataID: String = ""

    @State var isTapped: Bool = false


    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 80) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(exampleData) { data in
                    CardView(data: data)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.currentDataID = data.id
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 150)
            .animation(.easeOut, value: isDragging)
            // Gesture...
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .updating($isDragging, body: { _, out, _ in
                        out = true
                    })
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        // Only updating if dragging...
                        offset = isDragging ? value.location.x : 0

                        // Dragging space removing the padding added to the view...
                        // Total padding = 60
                        // 2 * 15 Horizontal
                        let draggingSpace = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60

                        // Each block...
                        let eachBlock = draggingSpace / CGFloat(exampleData.count)

                        // Getting index...
                        let temp = Int(offset / eachBlock)

                        // Safe wrapping index...
                        let index = max(min(temp, exampleData.count - 1), 0)

                        // Updating ID
                        self.currentDataID = exampleData[index].id
                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        withAnimation {
                            offset = .zero
                            currentDataID = ""
                        }
                    })
            )
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color("BackGround"))
                .frame(width: 160, height: 80)
                .overlay(
                    VStack(spacing: 8) {
                        Text("Average")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.065))
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)

                        Text("\(getDataNumber())")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.065))

                    }
                )

        }
    }

    func getXPosition() -> CGFloat {
        let index = exampleData.firstIndex { $0.id == currentDataID } ?? 0
        let barWidth: CGFloat = 30
        let spacing: CGFloat = 10
        let initialOffset: CGFloat = (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - CGFloat(exampleData.count) * (barWidth + spacing) + spacing) / 2
        return initialOffset + CGFloat(index) * (barWidth + spacing) + barWidth / 2
    }

    func getDataNumber() -> Int {
        if let data = exampleData.first(where: { $0.id == currentDataID }) {
            return Int(data.number)
        }
        return 0
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func CardView(data: ExampleData) -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                let size = proxy.size

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6)
                    .fill(data.color)
                    .opacity(isDragging || isTapped ? (currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0.35) : 1)
                    .frame(height: (data.number / getMax()) * (size.height))
                    .overlay(
                        Text("")
                            .opacity(isDragging && currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0)
                            .opacity(isTapped && currentDataID == data.id ? 1 : 0)
                            .offset(y: -30),
                        alignment: .top
                    )
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }

            Text(data.day)
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundColor((isDragging || isTapped) && currentDataID == data.id ? data.color : .gray)


        }
        .onTapGesture {
            isTapped.toggle()
            self.currentDataID = data.id

            if isTapped {
                self.currentDataID = data.id
            } else {
                currentDataID = ""
            }
        }
    }

    func getMax() -> CGFloat {
        let max = exampleData.max { first, second in
            return second.number > first.number
        }

        return max?.number ?? 0
    }
}
```

Comment: In this kind of test, you must change isTapped only if the tapped data is the current one. If not just change the current id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is the logic in

```
    .onTapGesture {
        isTapped.toggle()
        self.currentDataID = data.id

        if isTapped {
            self.currentDataID = data.id
        } else {
            currentDataID = ""
        }
    }
```

Having the `isTapped` in there makes no sense, and is forcing the double tap that you are complaining of. Your current logic is this:

1. isTapped starts as false
2. When any view in the ForEach is tapped, you toggle isTapped
3. isTapped is true
4. currentDataID is set to data.id
5. Since isTapped is now true, currentDataID is again set to data.id

On the next tap,

1. isTapped starts as true
2. When any view in the ForEach is tapped, you toggle isTapped
3. isTapped is false
4. currentDataID is set to data.id
5. Since isTapped is now false, currentDataID is set to ""

The next tap works like the first tap. To fix it, simply do this:

```
    .onTapGesture {
        if self.currentDataID == data.id {
            // deselects if you hit the same one twice
            self.currentDataID = ""
        }
            // changes to the new selection
            self.currentDataID = data.id
        }
    }
```

You can only keep one `currentDataID` at a time, so when the next one replaces the prior one, the prior one gets deselected and the next one gets selected. Otherwise, if you hit the same one twice in a row, `currentDataID` goes to "", the target is deselected.